# Java increment string through array

Tags: java

I don't know why I can't work this one in my head.

I have an array of characters in my Java code..

```
private String[] letters = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
    "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
};
```

What I need to do is loop through building strings for every possible configuration.

Example:

a
aa
ab
ac
.
.
.
aaa
aab
aac
.
.
.
.
aba
abc

and so on up to n length.

Can any one point me in the direction with this problem.

Cheers

Comment: @paislee If a finite number n is given for the maximum length then there is not an infinite number of possibilities.

Comment: [This post](http://abhisanoujam.blogspot.com/2010/05/superset.html) has an implementation of **superset generation** in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another recursive approach.  I'm working in the other direction from @liwp.  There's a slight advantage that I only allocate one output ArrayList.  Also, for simplicity, I just put in the numbers 0...9 in this example

```
static public void combos(String[] inputs, List<String> outputs, String preface, int maxDepth) {
        if (preface.length() >= maxDepth)
           return;
        for (String s : inputs) {
           // swap the order of these two lines if you want depth first
           outputs.add(preface+s);
           combos(inputs, outputs, preface+s, maxDepth);
        }       
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] numbers = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
        ArrayList<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();
        combos(numbers, outputs, "", 3);
        System.out.println(outputs);

     }
```

will print out

```
[0, 00, 000, 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 009, 01, 010, 011...
```

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about the strings less that `n`. That is, my solution produces only permutations of length `n`.

Comment: Edited it to do the strings of n, thanks for your help. Works great!

Comment: I should point out that my solution makes `n` calls to `permutations()`, whereas @user949300's solution makes `inputs.length^n` calls to `combos()`. OTOH @user949300's solution produces the requested output ordering, whereas my solution interleaves the shorter strings in between the longer strings.

Comment: My version also makes a somewhat non-robust check for the end condition.  It works for the example (where all the strings are of length 1) but might need improvement in other cases.

Comment: Great job. Working on this 4 DIN-A4 papers already. I am trying to calculate 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 10, 11. Hope this will bring the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need very long sequence you can use recursion like this:

```
for (String letter : letters) {
    String currentSequence = start + letter;
    System.out.println(currentSequence); // do something with your data here
    if (depth > 0) {
        printCombinations(currentSequence, depth - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.merriampark.com/comb.htm) method appears to be able to take a set and create the combinations like you are looking for.  You need to add the class to your project to be able to create a CombinationGenerator().

There doesn't appear to be only one way, but at least you would be able to copy in the method they used and call it.

```
String[] letters;
int[] indices;
CombinationGenerator x = new CombinationGenerator (letters.length, 3);
StringBuffer combination;
while (x.hasMore ()) {
  combination = new StringBuffer ();
  indices = x.getNext ();
  for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    combination.append (elements[indices[i]]);
  }
  System.out.println (combination.toString ());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion to the rescue!

```
static List<String> permutations(int len, String[] letters) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (len == 1) {
        ret.addAll(Arrays.asList(letters));
    } else {
        List<String> perms =  permutations(len - 1, letters);
        for (String l : letters) {
            ret.add(l);
            for (String s : perms) {
                ret.add(l + s);
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

**Update:** I tweaked the code to also produce permutations of `1` to `n-1` characters.

Notice that the output isn't ordered the same way as specified the by the OP. I wouldn't expect it to matter, but who knows...

Example output:

```
[0, 00, 000, 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 009, 01, 010, 011, ...]
```